# Migrating users table from Laravel to Ruby and using BCrypt to decode passwords does not work

Tags: ruby, laravel-4, bcrypt

I am migrating users table from a laravel application to a ruby SSO server, and I am using BCrypt to validate passwords in ruby.

The problem i am facing is that passwords do not match because the Hash generated by laravel starts with `$2y$10.....` and my BCrypt generates a hash `$2a$10....`

The versions between the two hashes do not match.
Ruby BCrypt shows version `2a`, instead laravel `2y`

How can i bring them on the same version so i can do user authentication in ruby like this?

`BCrypt::Password.new(user.send(password_column.to_sym)) == @password`

This should return true, but instead returns false.

`BCrypt::Password.new('$2y$10$tKrgxXzN.naFD3r//yX9/O5uJmGRA9lzlcoPgK.F8REX.kx9xOesS') == "Test1111!"`

Comment: You might have to rewrite `$2y` to `$2a` to get Bcrypt to understand that hash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PHP `crypt` method uses a non-standard notation for bcrypt-hashed entries. You need to correct this:

```
hash = '$2y$10$tKrgxXzN.naFD3r//yX9/O5uJmGRA9lzlcoPgK.F8REX.kx9xOesS'
BCrypt::Password.new(hash.sub(/\A\$2y/, '$2a')) ==  "Test1111!"
# => true
```

There was a bug in PHP's crypto library so `2y` represents the fixed version.