# Modifying the rails authenticate_user function to support PHPs non-standard bcrypt notation

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, laravel-5, bcrypt

I have a rails application that is using a Users table that was generated and filled via a laravel application.

the issue I'm having relates to another stackoverflow post

[Migrating users table from Laravel to Ruby and using BCrypt to decode passwords does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36164875/migrating-users-table-from-laravel-to-ruby-and-using-bcrypt-to-decode-passwords)

I need both applications to continue to work, but all the users are currently using PHPs non-standard notation for bcrypt-hashed passwords. The conversion is pretty easy. @tadman posted a solution on how to use the laravel generated password in ruby

`BCrypt::Password.new(hash.sub(/\A\$2y/, '$2a'))`

but now I'm trying to figure out how to actually use this for the rails authentication...

I've been looking into monkeypatching the `authenticate_user` method from `ActiveModel::SecurePassword` class but not sure if that is a good way to approach this.

Another way that I was thinking is making the appropriate change to all the users encrypted passwords to make them conform to the standard Bcrypt format, but then I would need to to make changes to how laravel's function to authecate users works... Ether way I have to change the implemention somewhere.

Is there a way that is less invasive into library code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unsure why I have a negative rating on this question but regardless I have figure out a way to do what I was asking. I monkey patched the authenticate method and tried to make it as clear as possible using folder structure.

I created a new directory called extentions in the `lib/` directory where I organized my monkeypatch based on what it was related to.

```
lib/ext/rails/secure_password.rb

module ActiveModel
  module SecurePassword
    module InstanceMethodsOnActivation

      def authenticate(unencrypted_password)
        BCrypt::Password.new(password_digest.sub(/\A\$2y/, '$2a')).is_password?(unencrypted_password) && self
      end

    end
  end
end
```

I also created an ext.rb file in the initializers directory that will load the monkeypatch class

```
config/initializers/ext.rb

Dir.glob(Rails.root.join('lib/ext/**/*.rb')).sort.each do |filename|
  require filename
end
```

this will work for any .rb files if you follow the pattern `lib/ext/{library_related_to_patch}/{name_of_file_containing_monkeypatch}.rb`